# Erlang: create filewatcher

Tags: erlang

I have to implement file watcher functionality in Erlang: There should be a process that list files if specific directory and do something, when files appear.

I take a look at OTP.  So at the moment I have following ideas:
1. Create Supervisor that will control  gen_servers (one server per folder)
2. Create WatchServer - gen_server for each folder that I want to monitor.
3. Create ProcessFileServer - gen server that should do something with files )assume copy to different folder=

So First problem: WatchServer should not wait for request, it should generate one in predefined intervals.

At the moment I have created a timer in init/1 function and handle on_timer event in handle_info function.

Now questions:
1. Are there better ideas?
2. How should I inform ProcessFileServer that file found? It seams to me that it would be much more convenient create WatchServers and ProcessServers independently, but in this case I do not know to whom send message?

May be there are some similar project/libs available?

Comment: As you look new to SO: avoid "Hello" and "Thanks" this is regarded as clutter, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/3021#3021 I have fixed your question already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Erlang it is very cheap to create processes (orders of magnitudes compared to other systems).

Therefore I recommend to create a new ProcessFileServer each time a new file to process is appearing.  When it is done with just terminate the process with exit reason `normal`.

I would suggest the following structure:

```
                              top_supervisor
                                      |
              +-----------------------+-------------------------+
              |                                                 |
       directory_supervisor                             processing_supervisor
               |                                         simple_one_for_one
    +----------+-----...-----+                                   |
    |          |             |                       starts children transient
    |          |             |                                   |
dir_watcher_1 dir_watcher_2 dir_watcher_n   +-------------+------+---...----+
                                            |             |                 |
                                        proc_file_1   proc_file_2       proc_file_n
```

When a `dir_watcher` notices a new file appeared. It calls the `processing_supervisor`s `supervisor:start_child\2` function, with the extra parameter of the file pathe e.g.

The `processing_supervisor` should start its children with `transient` restart policy.

So if one of the `proc_file` servers is crashing it will be restarted, but when they terminate with exit reason `normal` they are not restarted.  So you just exit `normal` when done and crash when whatever else happens.

If you don't overdo it, cyclic polling for files is Ok.  If the system becomes loaded because of this polling you can investigate in kernel notification systems (e.g. FreeBSD KQUEUE or the higher level services building upon it on MacOSX) to send you a message when a file appears in a directory.  These services however have a complexity because it is necessary for them to throw up their hands if too many events happen (otherwise they wouldn't be a performance improvement but the opposite).  So you will have to have a robust polling solution as a fallback anyway.

So don't do premature optimization and start with polling, adding improvements (which would be isolated in the `dir_watcher` servers) when it gets necessary.

---

Regarding the comment what behaviour to use as `dir_watcher` process since it doesn't use much of `gen_servers` functionality:

- There is no problem with only using part of `gen_servers` posibilities, in fact it is very common not to use all of it.  In your case you only set up a timer in `init` and use `handle_info` to do your work.  The rest of the `gen_server` is just the unchanged template.
- If you later want changing parameters like poll frequency it is easy to add into this.
- `gen_fsm` is much less used since it only fits a quite limited model and is not very flexible.  I use it only when it really fits 100% to the requirement (which it does almost never).
- In a case where you just want a simple plain Erlang server you can use the spawn functions in [`proc_lib`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/proc_lib.html) to get just the minimal functionality to run under a supervisor.
- A interesting way to write more natural Erlang code and still have the OTP advantages is [`plain_fsm`](https://github.com/uwiger/plain_fsm), here you have the advantages of selective receive and flexible message handling needed especially when handling protocols paired with the nice features of OTP.

Having said all this: if I would write a `dir_watcher` I'd just use a `gen_server` and use only what I need.  The unused functionality doesn't really cost you anything and everybody understands what it does.

Comment: Ok. Do not it look overcomplicated with 3 supervisors? Should dir_watcher be implemented as a gen_server, or better like gen_fsm? I've re read OTP manual, and looks like it is not fit to the concept of Server. There are no clients that ask them. It is more like a Hollywood: do not call us, we will call your.

Comment: @Anton: supervisors are much more lightweight than you probably think.   Once you get used to them and use them as small glue building blocks and build trees of them you'll use them more.  The trees you build out of them makes it possible to set the right supervisor setup like restart policies more precicesly.  The rest of your comment is answered above in the answer for better readability.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using Linux, you can use inotify. It is a kernel service that lets you subscribe to file system events. Don't poll the filesystem, let the filesystem call you.

you can try https://github.com/massemanet/inotify for observing your directory.

Ulf

Comment: This is an optimization that needs a robust polling solution first.  It is utterly OS dependent (done differently on Linux, FreeBSD, and MacOSX -- don't know if Windows supports this at all). While the system load of filesystem notification queues is preferable to polling, all sane kernel systems have the possibility that these queues overflow (otherwise they would bog down the system when lots of small files are created).  This is not an answer to the question on who to implement this cleanly in Erlang.

Comment: I believe the idea behind this answer is correct, write a `port` program that uses a native implementation that does this correctly and reliably. `inotify` on linux, `fsevents` on OSX and the equivalent system library on Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm under Windows, and to make life harder files are on network share.  As far as I know there are no way to get events under windows on network share.  And to be true I would prefer to have platform independent solution :)

Answer (score 2):

I have written such a library, based on polling. (It would be nice to extend it to use inotify on platforms where this is supported.) It was originally meant to be used in EUnit, but I turned into a separate project instead. You can find it here:

https://github.com/richcarl/file_monitor