# How can I tell if an open file has changed, in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I have opened a file (for read-only), and I'd like to know when it has changed (been added to, edited, or renamed and another file put in its place).  Is there a simple way to do this in Erlang?

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://github.com/richcarl/file_monitor

See also my answer to a similar older question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5696288/240949

Comment: Could you add an example of use?