# Does Erlang's ssh_sftp library provide for a way to listen for directory changes?

Tags: erlang, elixir

I need to watch or listen to a folder on an SFTP server for any changes. At some given time in the future (I don't know when), the folder will be updated with a file. Instead of pinging every minute, how would I setup a listener or watcher on that folder so I know when it has that file? Does Erlang's `ssh_sftp` module provide a function for this?

Comment: This is not the role of the `ssh_sftp` module to do this. You can read this related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682142/erlang-create-filewatcher).

Answer (score 0):

Neither SFTP nor FTP protocol have any mechanism to notify a client about changes in a remote folder. The only solution to detect changes is to periodically enumerate remote directory tree and find differences.

Ref : https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_watch_for_changes

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you still need it or not but I have already implemented what you need. I won't be able to share the code due to legal agreements however I can hint you the way to implement it.

Requirement: Run a function whenever a file lands to a directory instead of polling the directory at a defined interval to make processing efficient.

Step 1: Start the ssh daemon process with sftp as a subsystem

```
{ok, Pid} = ssh:daemon(Port, [{user_passwords, [{User, Pass}]},
                              {system_dir, SystemDir},
                              {user_dir, UserDir},
                              {key_cb, cac_auth},
                              {shell, {cacsftpd_server, display_info, []}},
                              {subsystems, [ssh_sftpd:subsystem_spec([{cwd, 
                               Home}, {file_handler, sftpd_file_handler}])]}])
```

Step 2: In sftpd_file_handler you can apply the trigger to call ur desired handler once the file is completely transferred ;)).

Answer (score 0):

While not in Erlang, but rather Elixir, take a look at: https://github.com/Codenaut/exsftpd/blob/master/lib/sftpd_file_handler.ex

The essential bit is the write function:

```
defmodule Exsftpd.SftpFileHandler do
...

  def write(io_device, data, state) do
    {:file.write(io_device, data), state}
    my_custom_function(state)
    {:ok, state}
  end

...
end
```

Here you can call whatever function you desire after (or instead of) writing the content to the filesystem.

Initialise the server like so: (see https://github.com/Codenaut/exsftpd/blob/master/lib/server.ex for a more elaborate example):

```
:ssh.daemon(2222,
    system_dir: '/tmp/ssh',
    subsystems: [
      Exsftpd.SftpdChannel.subsystem_spec(
        file_handler: {Exsftpd.SftpFileHandler, []}
      )
    ],
    user_dir: '/tmp/ssh/users'
  )
```